# Как трактуется выражение "вне периферии"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, значение-слов, предлоги

*Большая просьба: посмотрите отели **вне периферии** Калужско-Рижской линии.*

(Для "чистоты" вопроса не буду указывать тот смысл, который вкладывал.)

Увы, данная речевая конструкция была воспринята руководством некорректно, на мой взгляд, после чего меня попросили впредь писать "по-русски".

Справедливо ли?

Comment: _...после чего попросили писать "по-русски"..._  === Очень правильное пожелание!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Периферия — внешняя, противопоставленная центру часть чего-л. (П. сетчатки глаза. П. пожара. П. шторма.) Калужско-Рижская линия - это всего лишь линия ( не территория), поэтому трудно понять, что является ее центром, а что периферией. Можно предположить (с некоторой натяжкой), что периферия Калужско-Рижской линии это ее конечные станции. Таким образом, вы просили **посмотреть  отели, расположенные вне районов, прилегающих к конечным станциям Калужско-Рижской линии.**

Comment: Вы верно поняли, что я имел ввиду. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы тоже не понял, что такое противоположность периферии (вне её = где угодно, только не там), где её границы и по какую их сторону искать отели:

1) вряд ли ваше руководство смогло бы определить *границы периферии* названной линии,

2) невозможно заключить, действительно ли искать нужно ещё дальше, за периферией, или же можно поискать "не доходя" до периферии, т. е. в неких границах того, к чему она относится, а если можно, то где ближняя граница периферии, за которой искать не нужно?

Пожелание руководства о способе выражения считаю справедливым.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, он даёт понять, что формулировка всё же несёт некоторую неоднозначность. Впрочем, мне казалось очевидным, что "вне периферии" будет интерпретироваться исходя из законов логики:
- периферия есть не центр;
- вне есть отрицание пространства (не там, где);
- двойное отрицание (не там, где не центр = центр)

Answer (score 1):

Я не хочу "для чистоты эксперимента" читать другие ответы, поэтому - с листа.

Отвечаю на по сути на два вопроса. О самом сочетании и о его применении в конкретной фразе.

1. "Вне периферии" - в принципе возможное сочетание, хотя и непривычно. Тут дело в том, что "периферия" слово многозначное, в значении "удаленные районы" имеет некие границы, и, соответственно, нечто может быть **вне** этих границ. Да, это не совсем то, что сказал бы в этой ситуации человек, хорошо владеющий языком, но это только стилистическая помарка. А ведь есть еще варианты, когда, например, под "периферией" понимается все, что попадает в зону охвата периферического зрения... Тут вообще не придерешься.
2. Само высказывание про отели и линию, конечно, никуда не годится. Но причина не в сочетании "вне периферии", а в том, что у линии (даже Кольцевой, не только Калужско-Рижской) никакой периферии быть не может. На то она и линия.

Answer (score 0):

Периферия — термин не из точных наук, но всё-таки объяснимый: находящаяся на окраине части застройки, территории и т. д. Употреблённое сочетание *вне периферии* указывает на непризнание автором того факта, что внутренней границы между окраиной как части чего-то и не-окраиной (центром) быть не может. Они — одно целое. *Вне периферии* (хоть автор и не вкладывал такой смысл) должно бы означать некое сплющенное кольцо, вне которого и внутри которого (там и только там!) рекомендуется останавливаться на ночлег.

P.S. В городской среде границ между линиями (ветками) метро нет. Они существуют только как административные и зональные.